# how to create index for longtext (mysql, innodb)?

Tags: mysql, indexing, hash, innodb

I have longtext field "MYPARAMS" in my db. (mysql, inno). How can I create index for this field?

I read about index length but if the index is limited, how does MySQL deal with hash collisions?
I want to prevent situation when two different MYPARAMS will have the same index.

Comment: "when two different MYPARAMS will have the same index" - this doesn't make any sense. I presume you mean the same indexed value/same hash? Hash collisions can occur with short values too - a hash based index can accomodate such cases.

Comment: thanks, perhaps bad written, sorry. I just want to prevent collisions.

Answer (score 1):

> I have longtext field "MYPARAMS" in my db

You probably have a badly designed schema; the name implies a machine readable data format and the size + name implies a composite data structure. This should not be held in a single field.

> How can I create index for this field?

Analyze how you intended using the index and potential costs/benefits associated with the options. Without know what queries you will be writing against the dataset it is impossible to advise.

Comment: I think, I will make hash from MYPARAMS data (for example sha1) and store it in second field. For this field I will make index and this should work.

Comment: Yes, it should work.  But @symcbean's comments still stand.